# Modifiy Webbrowser User Agent to what?

Tags: firefox

I originally have this useragent (normal DesktopPC):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
```

but if I usually modifiy it to:

```
New -> String
general.useragent.override
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

in Firefox. Because I don't want to use my original useragent (because it could increase "security"... - to not to use the original..), but I don't want to break compatibility with websites.. but this option with "googlebot" useragent is not always the best solution because ex.: I can't check Gmail

But: I also don't want to use useragents like: "Mozilla/9.9 (X99; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:99.9) Gecko/99999999 Firefox/99.9" - because there are too unique.. so I could be easy identified..

**Q: What should I use as useragent to increase security?** I can't create a script that automagically modifies the useragent to the most commonly used one.

Comment: What do you expect to gain from changing your user-agent with regard to security?

Comment: avoid pls these kind of questions :D - because it's better to not provide the complete version information of the webbrowser that I'm using

Comment: Well, then it's not a serious question.

Comment: Well, then it's not a serious question. - WTF?

Comment: gasko - @HenningKlevjer is correct. The "why" of your situation is probably more important than any answer you would get, if any. Why are you doing this, what are you trying to achieve? Perhaps a better question would be "*Should* I change my useragent"... How to change it, and to what, would be a better fit on [su], if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real interest in changing your user-agent.

However, the most common user-agent is : `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)`

So using it makes you a (very very very very) little harder to identify (but it's really not a good way)

if you really mind about having an anonymous brother, i advise you to check it here : 
https://panopticlick.eff.org/

You'll understand identifying your browser is not about you user-agent ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand you well, but I [this will help you](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/), hoping :)